# 6-8 people dislike the question within 2 hours: why?

Tags: discussion, voting

[Can a question be bullshit?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/37868/can-a-question-be-bullshit) anyone at all want to say why this question is so bad?

Obviously enough people have read and disliked it for someone to answer.

I don't see what's unclear about it, either.

Also, consider [Is over conformity an issue on philosophy stackexchange?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3240/is-over-conformity-an-issue-on-philosophy-stackexchange)

Comment: My thoughts: you don't offer a definition of "bullshit". The question has no structure, and is instead a bunch of questions/thoughts soliciting our thoughts. This leaves a lot of interpretation/ambiguity to the answerer, which, as I commented on your previous post, is bad. Your question generally frames very little, and you've opted instead to throw a question with minimal context and hope it sticks. You're likely to elicit eclectic answers each focused on their own interpretation of what you've asked. This, too, is not very good.

Comment: @commando i don't define bullshit, no. i do though define the relation between bullshit and truth. the question clearly has the following structure: quote; question; elaboration on question; provisional answer. not at all sure what you mean by "frames very little", that is very ambiguous, or at least figurative? the context is the essay i link to. i'm leaving the site because of people who are so unhelpful. if questions have to have a definite and recognisable structure then define that.

Comment: I've answered the question because I felt the essay referenced was well-written, though it didn't go into the subject in any real depth and merely skirted issues of substance (and in fact, so did I); but I also agree that the question was a bit too informal; I had to read it a few times to understand what you were driving at. I do feel that the well-written paragraph has a lot going for it - but perhaps this kind of forum/platform - rather militates against this kind of writerly consideration?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Seeing as I've now had 7 upvotes since the question was edited to state where the quote from from:

- it's because you shouldn't link to articles without saying what they are in the main body of the question

Answer (score 6):

I'm sorely tempted to say the question is self-answering:

> I'm guessing that a ranted or rambling question can at least appear to be incoherent.

In my mind, that's exactly how your question reads. The quote you provided does not seem to be particularly relevant so I don't really see how the question engages with a philosophical school of thought. As it stands, the question seems to be of the "too informal" type warned against in the [help center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: no. you are wrong. it engages with the idea of "bullshit"

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN I can ask "what is infinity" and, by your criterion, be "engaging with the idea of 'infinity'". That does not make my question clear or good.

Comment: @commando if you link to an article in a seminal treatment of 'infinity' and quote from it saying why we have the idea and ask if infinity is X, then sure, why not?

Comment: "As an aside, meta is the place to ask meta questions. You made a series of comments aren't helpful, which I deleted."

Comment: @commando is that not pretty much what i did. i perfectly respect the idea that i'm who is mistaken, if only cos of weight of numbers weighing in. but...